# Can't use npm_modules after installation

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, bash

I'm starting a project where im going to use AngularJS, NodeJS and MySQL. This is my first real web application, and it's also the first time im using npm.

I've installed Node from their official website, and when i write npm install the node_modules comes to the project directory.

The problem occurs if I try to use any of the installed npm_modules. I tried to download mysql, and the installation worked, but when i type mysql -p i get: "bash: mysql: command not found"

I've also tried to install it with npm install mysql -g, but it still doesn't work.

If it means anything my $PATH is /usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin

Answer (score 1):

The mysql npm package contains just the nodejs client library for mysql. You need to install the mysql server separately using the appropriate method for your OS.

Comment: if your os is ubuntu you can use the instructions here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: i've installed the mysql server from their website, and i've set up the database. it still doesn't find the command.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have not installed mysql on your system.
install mysql server using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: the apt-get command doesn't work eiter, but i've installed the mysql server from their website, and i've set up the database. it still doesn't find the command.

Comment: @martin :which operating system you are using ?. the command i gave is for installing mysql server on Ubuntu or other debian system. which will setup a path variable so that your bash could find the command. add your mysqlserver installation path to PATH variable.